# Alter Profile with PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION return invalid function name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function that verify password for me as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_verification_function (
  username      VARCHAR2,
  password      VARCHAR2,
  old_password  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN AS
BEGIN
  IF LENGTH(password) < 8 THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
  ELSE
    RETURN TRUE;
  END IF;
END my_verification_function;
/
```

The function is created correctly I see it in the SQL Developer also I debug the function with values and it works correctly, but when I try to alter it to a profile where `RESOURCE_NAME` is `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` and the `RESOURCE_TYPE` is `PASSWORD` the LIMIT is `NULL` and COMMON is `NO` so I use this alter `ALTER PROFILE MY_PROFILE LIMIT
  PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION MY_VERIFICATION_FUNCTION;` and it returns me

```
SQL Error: ORA-07443: function MY_VERIFICATION_FUNCTION not found
07443. 00000 -  "function %s not found"
*Cause:    An invalid function name was specified.
*Action:   Use a valid function name.
```

Comment: Edit your question and share the current code of the `FUNCTION`, which is throwing an error.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 the function works I already wrote that, but when I try to alter it then it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Password Verification policy

> The password verification routine must be owned by the `SYS`

Refer to [**this link**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/policies.htm#i1007340)